# Raspberry Pi C++ I2C/SPI Examples

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, i2c, spi

Hello and please do not delete right away. I'm having trouble finding good CODE examples for the I2C/SPI programming on the Raspberry Pi using C++. I've looked at wiringPi and other sources but they don't give much documentation with their source code as I would like. Has anyone found pleasant examples in either well documented source code or even video explanations? If you have could you please share a link?

Thank you!

Comment: The request of libraries, tutorials or similar are off-topic in SO

Comment: Suggestion for where I should move it? perhaps StackExchange?

Comment: see this: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @eyllanesc No. This question is off-topic there too. See the [Help Center there](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "But please note that the following is off topic" "Asking for references to online material (use a search engine, and if that does not work, ask about the issue directly)"

Comment: do not know the rules of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com, I only recommended that you find out if you can post it there.

Answer (score 2):

Doing I2C in C on Raspberry Pi is easy -- mostly you need ordinary low-level file operations -- open, read, write, etc.

First open the appropriate device:

```
int f = open ("/dev/i2c-1", O_RDWR);
```

Then use `ioctl()` to set the I2C device address:

```
ioctl (f, I2C_SLAVE, address);
```

Then just use ordinary `read()` and `write()` calls to send and receive data.

The hard part is understanding the data protocol of the device -- this may, or may not, be documented. For RPi, many vendors only provide Python programming examples, so we have to reverse-engineer the actual protocol from the Python code.

I've used this method for interfacing all manner of devices to the RPi -- displays, motors, sensors, etc. Honestly, reading and writing the I2C bus is very much the *easy* part of the job :)

Comment: But how do you do that in modern C++? Specifically, what are the files to include, and what namespace do those functions belong to?

Comment: read(), write(), ioctl() are in the global namespace, so you should be able to write "::read(...)", etc., in C++. You shouldn't need to include anything else. Having said that, there might be class libraries for C++ that wrap I2C operations. If there are, these might be easier to use than low-level function calls.

Comment: Of course you are right; my expectation was std::, but of course, I was wrong on that one...